# assigning function to elements of array . How to bind output of function?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, closures

I am trying to create a 'secret' guestList to practice some closures and binding in JS. I am currently stuck because I need to use binding so the value of `i` updates after every iteration but I am really new to biding and I am having trouble wrapping my head around this... how do I call my variable `code` from the closure? how do I correctly bind the guesName to my checkCode function? :/

Here my code :

```
function guestListFns(guestList, secretCode){
    var topSecretList = []; 
    function codeChecker(code) {
        if (code === secretCode) {
            return guestName;
        } else {
            return "Secret-Code: Invalid";
        }
    };
    for(var i = 0 ; i < guestList.length; i += 1){
        var guestName = guestList[i]; 
            topSecretList.push(codeChecker.call(this.guestName, code));
    }
    console.log(topSecretList);

        return topSecretList; 
}
```

my testing values :

```
    var guestListFns = guestListFns(["Gabriel", "Ben", "Dan", "Griffin", "Cang", "Kate", "Chris"], 512);

var guest = guestListFns[1](512);
console.log(guest);
```

my return value so far:

```
"code is not defined"
```

Also, I have already figured out how to implement this function simply using map. But what I meant with this exercise is to practice binding so I can understand the concept.

Thanks!

Comment: it is completely unclear whatyou actually want as you are mixing up a few things

Comment: I would love to understand what is the correct way to bind my checkCode function to each guestName and assign that checkCode function to the my topSecretList arr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this be what you're looking for?

```js
function guestListFns(guestList, secretCode){
    var topSecretList = []; 
    function codeChecker(code) {
        if (code === secretCode) {
            return this.guestName;
        } else {
            return "Secret-Code: Invalid";
        }
    };
    for(var i = 0 ; i < guestList.length; i += 1){
        var guestName = guestList[i]; 
        topSecretList.push(codeChecker.bind({guestName:guestName}));
    }
    console.log(topSecretList);

        return topSecretList; 
}

var gfn = guestListFns(["Gabriel", "Ben", "Dan", "Griffin", "Cang", "Kate", "Chris"], 512);
gfn.forEach(f => console.log(f(512)));
```

Comment: Thanks @TKol , yes. This solution apparently solves the binding of checkCode inside my loop. Now, any idea of why my topSecretList is filled with `null` instead of the function checkCode itself? For some reason I can't get the push to pass the function instead of its return value... some guidance is fine. It is just a really confusing topic.

Comment: when I run mine, it's not filled with null.

Comment: Weird. In my case it returns `[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
'Gabriel'
'Ben'
'Dan'
'Griffin'
'Cang'
'Kate'
'Chris'`  :/

Comment: you should try console.logging the typeof the contents of topSecretList, `topSecretList.forEach(f => console.log(typeof f))`

Comment: Right! they appear to be functions... thank you so much! I am still a bit confused as for why the `null` in my array but it seems like internally is working.

Answer (score 1):

You dont wanna `call`, but you want to `bind`:

```
codeChecker.bind({ guestName })
```

So now inside codeChecker you can access

```
this.guestName
```

---

Actually you are overcomplicating things:

```
 const guestListFns = (arr, secret) =>
   arr.map(el => code => code === secret ? el : "nope");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas . I actually had figured out already how to use map. But, as stated in the question, my idea is to understand binding. In your answer to my question :  when you use the {} around guestName, should I use them too?? After using `bind` instead of `call` and using `this.guestName` inside my checkCode function, i get `undefined` : /

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying, I think `call()` is the wrong way to go about this. You want an array of partial functions where each function already has the name. You can use `bind()` for this. `call()` actually invokes the function, which isn't what you really want here. `bind()` returns a new function and allows you to set `this` and/or some of the arguments:

```js
function guestListFns(guestList, secretCode){
    var topSecretList = []; 
    function codeChecker(guestName, code) {
        if (code === secretCode) {
            return guestName;
        } else {
            return "Secret-Code: Invalid";
        }
    };
    for(var i = 0 ; i < guestList.length; i += 1){
        var guestName = guestList[i]; 
        topSecretList.push(codeChecker.bind(null, guestName));
    }

    return topSecretList; 
}

var guestListFns = guestListFns(["Gabriel", "Ben", "Dan", "Griffin", "Cang", "Kate", "Chris"], 512);

console.log(guestListFns[1](512)); // ben
console.log(guestListFns[2](512)); // dan
console.log(guestListFns[1](112)); // bad code
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, as I in the previews answer, after modifying my code following your answer, my output is  `[ null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
'Gabriel'
'Ben'
'Dan'
'bad code `

I wonder why isn't `.push` passing the function into topSecretList instead of `null`  :/